# Java2D почему при прокрутке съезжает курсор относительно узла сетки?

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь нарисовать сетку и привязать курсор к узлам этой сетки. Унаследовал класс от JPanel, нарисовал на нём сетку, обработал мышь, задал всему этому делу большой размер и положил в JScrollPane, чтобы прокрутка была. И всё вроде бы нормально, но заметил, что если сдвинуть скроллбар вправо, т.е подвинуть панель внутри окна, то курсор(мой нарисованный крестик) перестаёт точно вставать в узлы сетки. Если сдвинуть скроллбары в нулевую позицию(т.е горизонтальный полностью влево, а вертикальный полностью вверх  viewport.x=0 и viewport.y=0) то всё работает нормально.  Изначально грешил на то что не учитываю позицию viewport-а, но вроде бы нет, своевременно перевожу координаты из оконных в мировые и обратно, да и вычитание позиции viewport-а ничего не даёт. Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка, а то уже голову сломал?

```
public class DrawArea extends JPanel implements MouseListener, 
                                                MouseMotionListener, 
                                                MouseWheelListener  {
```

`private int aDPI = 300;

/** По умолчанию панель будет размером с лист А4 */
private Dimension aSize               = TR_Utils.mmsToPixels(TR_Utils.A4_PAGE_SIZE_MM, aDPI);  
private Dimension operateAreaSize     = new Dimension(aSize);
 /** Коэффициент зумирования */
private double  scaleFactor           = 5.0;

/** Размер сетки(в пикселах), если включена */
private int     aGridSize             = TR_Utils.mmsToPixels(0.01, aDPI);
private int operateGridSize           = aGridSize;

/** Позиция курсора - позиция от которой рисуем(в логических, мировых координатах) */
private Point crossHairPosition       = new Point(0, 0);
/** Привязывать ли курсор к сетке */
private boolean snapCursorToGrid      = true;
/** Включаем выключаем сетку */
private boolean isGridEnabled         = true;
/** Крест по центру экрана, если надо */
private boolean isCrossEnabled        = true;
/** Сглаживание, если требуется */
private boolean isAnlialiasingEnabled = false;

/** Включен режим рисования(рисуется курсор для 
 * рисования на панели, иначе простой указатель) */
private boolean isDrawMode            = true;
private boolean isShowCrossHair       = isDrawMode;  
/** Включен ли режим просмотра для панели.
 * В этом режиме запрещено редактировать или что-либо рисовать на панели,
 * события мыши и клавиатуры игнорируются, изображение на панели 
 * панорамируется(если необходимо) */
private boolean isViewMode            = false;

/** Координата, на которой нажали кнопку */
private Point mousePressedPos;

//GridSize s = new GridSize(15, SizeMeasureUnits.MIL);

private AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

public DrawArea() {
    setPreferredSize(operateAreaSize);
    System.out.println("Size w: " + aSize.width + " h: " + aSize.height);

    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseWheelListener(this); 
    validate();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(operateAreaSize);
}


public void setCenterInViewport() {
    Container parent = getParent();
    if (parent instanceof JViewport) {

        JViewport port = (JViewport)parent;
        Rectangle viewRect = port.getViewRect();

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        viewRect.x = (width - viewRect.width) / 2 - viewRect.x;
        viewRect.y = (height - viewRect.height) / 2 - viewRect.y;

        port.scrollRectToVisible(viewRect);
    }
}

/** Находит ближайший узел сетки для установки курсора.
  * curX, curY - координаты курсора в мировых координатах */
private Point getNearestGridPosition(int curX, int curY) {

    int cellx = (int)Math.round(curX / operateGridSize);
    int celly =  (int)Math.round(curY / operateGridSize);

    int x = cellx * operateGridSize;
    int y = celly * operateGridSize; 


    System.out.println("Grid size: " + aGridSize + " ScaleFactor: " + scaleFactor + " operateGridSize: " + operateGridSize);
    System.out.println("Cursor pos - x: " + curX + " y: " + curY);
    System.out.println("Cell num - x: " + cellx + " y: " + celly);
    System.out.println("CrossHairPos - x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    return new Point(x, y);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    /* Prepare draw area */
    if(isGridEnabled) {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
      //  int gridStep = (int)(gridSize * Math.round(scaleFactor));
       // int gridStep = (int) Math.floor(gridSize * scaleFactor);

        g2d.setColor(new Color(235, 235, 235));
        System.out.print("X draw values:");
        for(int i = operateGridSize; i < w; i += operateGridSize) {
            g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, h);
            if( i <= w/7)
                System.out.print(" " + i);    
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int j = operateGridSize; j < h; j += operateGridSize) 
            g2d.drawLine(0, j , w, j);
    }



    if (isShowCrossHair) {
        int cs = 12; // размер крестика-курсора в пикселях
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        /* Координаты курсора в мировых координатах, приведем их к оконным */
        int cx = (int)crossHairPosition.getX(); 
        int cy = (int)crossHairPosition.getY();

        Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(cx, cy), getParent());

        g2d.drawLine(p.x-cs/2, p.y, p.x+cs/2, p.y);
        g2d.drawLine(p.x, p.y-cs/2, p.x, p.y+cs/2);
    }


    g2d.dispose();

}


/****** MOUSE EVENTS  ******/

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    mousePressedPos = me.getPoint();
    System.out.println("mousePressedPos " + mousePressedPos.x + "/" + mousePressedPos.y);
    if(SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(me)) {
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        isShowCrossHair = false;
        repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    isShowCrossHair = true;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    if(!isViewMode) {
        if(SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(me)) {
            if(mousePressedPos != null) {

                JViewport port = (JViewport)getParent();
                Rectangle viewRect = port.getViewRect(); 

                int deltaX = mousePressedPos.x - me.getX();
                int deltaY = mousePressedPos.y - me.getY();

                viewRect.x += deltaX;
                viewRect.y += deltaY;

                scrollRectToVisible(viewRect);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    if(!isViewMode) {
        int x = me.getX();
        int y = me.getY();

        // в мировые координаты
        Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(getParent(), new Point(x, y), this);
        JViewport port = (JViewport)getParent();
        Point vp = port.getViewPosition();

        System.out.println( "cur_wnd.x: " + x + " cur_wnd.y: " + y + 
                            " / cur_world.x: " + p.x + " cur_world.y: " + p.y + 
                            " / viewpos.x: " + vp.x + " viewpos.y: " + vp.y);

        if(snapCursorToGrid) {
            // Привязываем курсор к узлам сетки
            Point np = getNearestGridPosition(p.x, p.y);
            crossHairPosition.setLocation(np.x, np.y);
        }
        else {
            crossHairPosition.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent mwe) {
    if(!isViewMode) {
        /* минус для изменения направления движения колесика при маштабировании, так удобнее */
        scaleFactor += -(0.05 * mwe.getWheelRotation());
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.05, scaleFactor);
        scaleFactor = Math.min(scaleFactor, 10);

        // пересчитываем размер области рисования
        operateAreaSize.setSize((int)(aSize.width * scaleFactor), 
                                (int)(aSize.height * scaleFactor));

        System.out.println("scaleFactor: " + scaleFactor);

        // пересчитываем размер сетки
        operateGridSize = (int)Math.round(aGridSize * scaleFactor);
        System.out.println("operateGridSize(px): " + operateGridSize);

        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}`

}

Comment: по-моему, эти конверсии не нужны, в событиях мыши позиция курсора приходит в координатной системе вашей `DrawArea`, рисуете вы в ней же. Крестик перестает точно вставать в сетку, потому что вы выполняете деление в координатах viewport, а сетка у вас смещается.

Comment: В событиях координаты придут в к.с DrawArea (т.е совпадут с координатами на DrawArea), только если я не буду двигать скроллбаром, если сдвину его, то к координате мыши нужно прибавить ещё сдвиг вьюпорта, для этого и использую конверсию координат. В функцию getNearestGridPosition - которая вычисляет ближайший узел сетки, я передаю координаты, предварительно переведя их в систему DrawArea(т.е в мировые координаты), отсюда у меня и смущение. Вроде бы всё как-надо, а не понимаю, из-за чего сдвиг происходит (